# Where do pointers point to exactly when declared?

Tags: c++, pointers

If I declare a pointer to use as a "dynamic array" like this:

```
int *arr;
```

Without using the `new` keyword or specifying any size.

Is this bad code? Where exactly does this pointer point to?

And in the case let's say I initialize the array like following:

```
arr = new int[5];
```

Then make this call (which works for me):

```
arr[100] = 10;
```

Could I overwrite some other data accidentally this way? (so far this never happened to me). is there a "safety threshold" as to how many consecutive blocks that are left free after this pointer declaration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A pointer variable is just another kind of variable. Its value depends on its storage duration (which isn't shown in your question).

- Static or thread storage duration objects are zero-initialized.
- Automatic storage duration objects have an indeterminate value. (These are the regular "local variables" we declare inside functions.)

Reading an indeterminate value invokes *undefined behavior*. Programs that do that are incorrectly written - even though they may appear to work sometimes. Undefined behavior explicitly imposes no requirements on the implementation, including no requirement for a safety threshold before you start overwriting neighboring data.

But the above only concerns the "dynamic" consequences of invoking undefined behavior (which is what most people tend to focus on). Undefined behavior can have even stranger "static" consequences.

Code that can be inferred ahead-of-time to invoke undefined behavior (whether it's for all cases or just for some values of some expressions in your code) allows the compiler to take less obvious decisions, including removing function calls or even entire branches of code, even in functions that are unrelated to yours (such as modifying the caller of the erroneous function). Raymond Chen has expanded on this in [a very informative blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633) (that I often refer people to, because it highlights the "static" consequences of UB in great detail).

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation.  The second part of my question though(which might be a bit irrelevant) : if say I declare a pointer like this:
int *p = new int[5];
p[100] = 10;

What happens here? how much memory is initially reserved? Do I just overwrite other data here, or is there a re-allocation when I make such a call?

Comment: @AhmedElyamani The memory that's reserved in that declaration is at least enough to hold 5 `int`s. Any additional memory reserved (for bookkeeping or alignment) is generally not accessible to user code. Indexing an array out of its valid bounds (whether for reading or writing) does not trigger a re-allocation. It simply falls into UB territory again. (Overwriting other data is one of the possible scenarios.)

Comment: @AhmedElyamani: You should prefer smart-pointers and containers. Aside from that, how else would you use them if not using pointers?

Comment: If you are certain you're going to use them correctly, there's nothing wrong with C-style arrays, in my opinion. However, starting with C++11 there's an `std::array` that works similarly to C-style arrays and offers optional bounds checking (among other things). And there's also `std::vector` and the rest, as you know.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, High-risk of Manipulation the variable data execution time of the program by another program. Dynamically+Without size declaration is not good practice. The memory occupied at run time so addresses are allocated that time. If a specific location is defined by you in address memory that available(empty) then the program will run and specific memory does not move until program terminated. if the specific location occupied than the program will not execute.